# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I'm making a react app using Babel and Webpack and I want to use the `file-exists` package from npm. I already installed and saved the package as a dependency for my project. After running npm start I get this error:

> ERROR in ./~/file-exists/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in C:\GitHub\CryptoPrices\node_modules\file-exists
>   @ ./~/file-exists/index.js 3:9-22

`file-exists` uses `fs` as a dependency but for some reason it is not working. Npm starts and runs without any issues if I don't require `file-exists` anywhere.

here is my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      // exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

I'm new to Webpack and Babel so I'm a little bit lost.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you're calling the `fs` `file-exists` method in your `index.js` file. I'm not sure in what context you're calling the method, but this looks like a client-side call to a server-side method. I ran into a similar issue just recently.

From what I understand, the main issue seems to be that you can't call server-side (Node) methods in browser-interpreted client-side (front end) code. You have to call them from a server.

Webpack can load the `fs` module code into your front end, but the browser can't actually interpret those Node methods and run them; only a Node environment can do that. [(more here)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JavaScript-and-Node-js/answer/Corey-Butler?share=7a58545f)

You could fix the core issue by modifying the call to `fs` methods to happen somewhere server-side, or by finding an equivalent browser-supported package that offers the same functionality as the `fs` methods you need but that can be run in a browser.

A quick search for "fs module for browser" brings up a variety of options that might work for what you need, like [fs-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-web), [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) or [filer](https://github.com/filerjs/filer).

Here is a similar question with some insight.
[Use fs module in React.js,node.js, webpack, babel,express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983275/use-fs-module-in-react-js-node-js-webpack-babel-express)

Comment: You might also find this thread interesting. It's discussing a similar situation using fs in the browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467858/manipulating-the-local-file-system-with-browser-based-javascript-and-node

Comment: Here's another related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951874/problems-running-node-js-in-browser

Comment: And another thread on this topic... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959868/differences-between-node-environment-and-browser-javascript-environment

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This error was annoying us for so long. Finally moved the code from the NextJS module to the Cloud Functions module and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

try to add the code above to your webpack config file and the error should disappear.

Comment: I already tried that, the error disappears but then file-exists doesn't work