# Can I export variables from server.js? (or best way to transfer environment variables)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

so essentially, for the purposes of testing locally, I need to define my API keys in a `.env` file and the only place I can read them into my code is in my `server.js` file.

as an example, let's say in my `server.js`, I have the following code with the necessary imports:

`const {api_key1, api_key2} = process.env;`

I thought I would try to be clever and try the following:

`export default {api_key1, api_key2};`

so I could then `import server from 'server.js';` from a front end javascript file, like `index.js`.

Of course, I tried running that and was greeted with **SyntaxError: Unexpected token export**

**TLDR:
What's the best way to transfer these environment variables into other JSX files?**

Follow up edits:

when I try `const {apikey1, apikey2} = process.env` in `index.js`, I get **Reference Error: Process is not defined**

when I try adding a `require('dotenv').config()` above the process.env call, I get **Module not found: can't resolve 'fs' in ..node_modules\dotenv\lib**

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You are misled when you're thinking about doing so.

**You don't need to export those variables**, these are **implicitly available** in process object. So you can access those in any file like the same way you're doing in server.js.

Like, in `index.js` you can do something like `const {api_key1, api_key2} = process.env;` and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: So I saw this SO thread earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359480/8652920

and from what I can tell using dotenv/process.env in `index.js` is a big no no?

Comment: My code has `const dotenv = require('dotenv');` and the exact code you mentioned in `index.js` right now, and on compile I'm getting the classic `Cant resolve 'fs' in ...node_modules\dotenv\lib`

Comment: You are doing that for client side application or server-side ?

Comment: @ark0n Did you go through - https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/233#issuecomment-339066486 ?

Comment: I'm requiring dotenv and accessing process.env in `index.js` at the moment, and the api key pops up on the screen for a brief second (because i added it as a header for the page) and then the fs error comes

Comment: DotEnv is not supported for client side applications, please check the link a pasted.

Comment: and @DJ Yadav, I added both the linked webpack config and `target: "node"`, none of which are allowing me to use `process` in `index.js`