# React - Cannot find module fs and require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using React to build a web app. I never called `fs` in a file and everything worked fine until I suddenly got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'
```

So I then googled how to resolve this, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249719/9878135).
When following this answer I then get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

[Making fs an empty object raises the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359134/9878135).

Does someone know how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

Full output of the first error:

```
main.js:24 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'
    at webpackMissingModule (main.js:24)
    at Object.eval (main.js:24)
    at eval (main.js:115)
    at Object../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js (bundle.js:73895)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (index.tsx:6)
    at Module../src/index.tsx (bundle.js:76423)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:84
    at bundle.js:87
```

Here's `bundle.js:73895`:

```
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(process) {/* @flow */\n/*::\n\ntype DotenvParseOptions = {\n  debug?: boolean\n}\n\n// keys and values from src\ntype DotenvParseOutput = { [string]: string }\n\ntype DotenvConfigOptions = {\n  path?: string, // path to .env file\n  encoding?: string, // encoding of .env file\n  debug?: string // turn on logging for debugging purposes\n}\n\ntype DotenvConfigOutput = {\n  parsed?: DotenvParseOutput,\n  error?: Error\n}\n\n*/\n\nconst fs = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error(\"Cannot find module 'fs'\"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()))\nconst path = __webpack_require__(/*! path */ \"./node_modules/path-browserify/index.js\")\n\nfunction log (message /*: string */) {\n  console.log(`[dotenv][DEBUG] ${message}`)\n}\n\nconst NEWLINE = '\\n'\nconst RE_INI_KEY_VAL = /^\\s*([\\w.-]+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)?\\s*$/\nconst RE_NEWLINES = /\\\\n/g\nconst NEWLINES_MATCH = /\\n|\\r|\\r\\n/\n\n// Parses src into an Object\nfunction parse (src /*: string | Buffer */, options /*: ?DotenvParseOptions */) /*: DotenvParseOutput */ {\n  const debug = Boolean(options && options.debug)\n  const obj = {}\n\n  // convert Buffers before splitting into lines and processing\n  src.toString().split(NEWLINES_MATCH).forEach(function (line, idx) {\n    // matching \"KEY' and 'VAL' in 'KEY=VAL'\n    const keyValueArr = line.match(RE_INI_KEY_VAL)\n    // matched?\n    if (keyValueArr != null) {\n      const key = keyValueArr[1]\n      // default undefined or missing values to empty string\n      let val = (keyValueArr[2] || '')\n      const end = val.length - 1\n      const isDoubleQuoted = val[0] === '\"' && val[end] === '\"'\n      const isSingleQuoted = val[0] === \"'\" && val[end] === \"'\"\n\n      // if single or double quoted, remove quotes\n      if (isSingleQuoted || isDoubleQuoted) {\n        val = val.substring(1, end)\n\n        // if double quoted, expand newlines\n        if (isDoubleQuoted) {\n          val = val.replace(RE_NEWLINES, NEWLINE)\n        }\n      } else {\n        // remove surrounding whitespace\n        val = val.trim()\n      }\n\n      obj[key] = val\n    } else if (debug) {\n      log(`did not match key and value when parsing line ${idx + 1}: ${line}`)\n    }\n  })\n\n  return obj\n}\n\n// Populates process.env from .env file\nfunction config (options /*: ?DotenvConfigOptions */) /*: DotenvConfigOutput */ {\n  let dotenvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')\n  let encoding /*: string */ = 'utf8'\n  let debug = false\n\n  if (options) {\n    if (options.path != null) {\n      dotenvPath = options.path\n    }\n    if (options.encoding != null) {\n      encoding = options.encoding\n    }\n    if (options.debug != null) {\n      debug = true\n    }\n  }\n\n  try {\n    // specifying an encoding returns a string instead of a buffer\n    const parsed = parse(fs.readFileSync(dotenvPath, { encoding }), { debug })\n\n    Object.keys(parsed).forEach(function (key) {\n      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(process.env, key)) {\n        process.env[key] = parsed[key]\n      } else if (debug) {\n        log(`\"${key}\" is already defined in \\`process.env\\` and will not be overwritten`)\n      }\n    })\n\n    return { parsed }\n  } catch (e) {\n    return { error: e }\n  }\n}\n\nmodule.exports.config = config\nmodule.exports.parse = parse\n\n/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(this, __webpack_require__(/*! ./../../process/browser.js */ \"./node_modules/process/browser.js\")))\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js?");
```

It seems to be something with `dotenv`. I used to have this package but I just removed it.

Comment: looks like some issue with you build/babel/webpack.

Comment: Does it give any indication where the fs module is being used?

Comment: it looks like you are now setting target for node where it would be using node api causing the problem. Can you share your webpack config?

Comment: `Object../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js` — probably you need to exclude this from your bundle

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this helps but I had this error when autocorrect decided to add

```
import { render } from 'node-sass'
```

to one of my React components. Check you have the correct imports.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You are possibly missing a package.

Just try to install the package `fs.promises` to solve your issue.